# One Big Bang or one 'Bang' per galaxy?

Tags: cosmology

Can the big bang theory be applied to individual galaxies?
If 'yes', then this raises questions about a progressive initiation of galaxy bangs in a developing unniverse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The evidence shows that all galaxies in the observable universe originated from the same tiny volume 14 billion years ago. Formation of galaxies happened some time after that, in a process different from a 'big bang'- the matter forming our galaxy did not originate in a small volume and expanded from that.